# How to find digits in String by regular expression?

Tags: regex

I have next string: `12, "User01", 22, true, -8`

I should receive: `12, 22, -8.`

I used `/\d+/g`, but its return: 12, 01, 22, 8 and that is not I needed.

Comment: A pattern like `/-?\b\d+\b/g` might do.

Comment: thanks you,  Wiktor Stribiżew, it is working!

Comment: It's not clear if '01' in "User01" is not extracted because it starts with a zero, is in a quoted string or is immediately preceded by a letter (rather than a space, for example). That could be made clear by writing your example string differently, perhaps `'12, "User 92 excelled", 22, 17A, true, -8, 06'`.